# Is there any way to change custom task pane color in VSTO outlook add in?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

Is there any way to change custom task pane background color in mail compose window ?

**UPDATE**

UserControl.BackColor gives me this result. But I want whole custom task pane to be white

[image]

My code for setting up usercontrol is here:

```
public partial class UserControlTest : UserControl
{
    public UserControlTest()
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.White;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of the task panel by setting the `BackColor` of the `UserControl`.

This is how I set mine to the same color as Visual Studios dark theme:

```
private const string WindowColor = @"#FF2D2D30";
...
var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(WindowColor);
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

I do this within the constructor of the `UserControl` before calling `this.InitializeComponent();`.

Comment: UserControl.BackColor not fill all task pane with specified color. I added result in my question

Comment: @IvanZaporozhchenko can you post you're code where you build the `UserControl` as this is the exact code I use so it'd be good to see if there are differences to how you setup the control. I also presume that you are using a WinForm UserControl? Also are you embedding a WPF control within the WinForm?

Comment: I added code. I'm using WinForm user control. Actually, I want to embed WPF control inside WinForm control, but there is no difference, I tried control without embedding WPF, and I have the same result.

Comment: Is it the borders/header that you want to change, as I don't believe there is anyway to change the border color. Only the background which looks like white to me in the image, but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: So there is no way to change the header color? I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154517/dynamically-match-custom-task-pane-content-background-color-to-header-background

Comment: @Midas I was unable to get the header colour to change. It's possible that there is a way I've never encountered it though.

Comment: I  think he is not referreing to the user control's background color. He is referreing to the background color of the custom  task pane title bar and borders which is totally different and maybe not possible unless you do a Kind of hack using windows API functions or hooks.