# Is there any way to change border/header background in VSTO outlook add in?

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, vsto

[image]

I'm developing a VSTO plugin for Outlook 2016 but am not able to change the border and header background color (as you can see from the linked image).

I tried to force the "BackColor" property of the `TaskPaneWpfControlHost` object but what happens is that I get the background change of the user control injected into the container.

```
     public TaskPaneWpfControlHost(System.Windows.Controls.UserControl shell)
    {
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        InitializeComponent();
        wpfElementHost.HostContainer.Children.Add(shell);
        wpfElementHost.AutoSize = true;
        wpfElementHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _shell = shell;
    }
```

Comment: Did you finally suceed? If so how did you get it? Could you please share it? I am trying to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BackColor refer to the below code:

```
private const string WindowColor = @"#FF2D2D30";

var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(WindowColor);
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);
```

For more information, Please refer to the below link:

[Is there any way to change custom task pane color in VSTO outlook add in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706011/is-there-any-way-to-change-custom-task-pane-color-in-vsto-outlook-add-in)

[How to: Set the Background of a Windows Forms Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-background-of-a-windows-forms-panel)

Comment: It doesn't work..if I change code like below header and border have always gray background:

Comment: Inside ctor (before initializeComponent):   var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(WindowColor);
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(color.R, color.G, color.B);

Comment: Outside like private const: private const string WindowColor = @"#FF2D2D30";

Comment: Please, note that my goal is to change the appearance about the window title bar which I mean the native part of Outlook window

Comment: @FraDamm if you do this inside the constructor of the user control, even before initialize, it does not work and maybe it throws an exception because you are trying to do things over components that are not initialized yet. User control is embedded within the custom task pane, when you use this.backcolor you are changing the color of the user control itself,  not the one from the custom task pane (header and borders). It's totally diferent.

Answer (score 0):

I think Outlook Object Model does not provide any mechanism to do this. Maybe you can do it using a kind of hack using Windows API functions or hooks.

AFAIK The title bar (header), buttons and borders of the custom task pane are managed and drawn by Outlook VSTO itslef. In fact the custom task pane is a borderless window but VSTO adds the rest (borders, title bar - header -, buttons).