# Outlook Web-add in - Change color of the title bar

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to change the color of the title bar in my addin.

I see  in the xml file which produces the title on the title bar. What is the correct way to hook into the title bar?

I see something similar question for C#
[Is there any way to change border/header background in VSTO outlook add in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285132/is-there-any-way-to-change-border-header-background-)
in-vsto-outlook-add-in

Please see attach photo to the area I want to change the background color for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently this capability (changing the color of the title bar) is not available for add-ins. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins