# Office 365 Outlook add-in Titlebar

Tags: user-experience, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

I am developing an add-in for Outlook Office 365, and there is one thing that presents a challenge.

The little x in the top right corner that closes the add-in will discard all changes made in the add-in if the user hasn't already saved the changes using my own save button. I cannot react to an event thrown when the user clicks that x, and that way either stop them or autosave. Such an event isn't thrown.

So what I would like to do instead is to make it a little more visible that the x is one that closes everything. I would like to do that by coloring the titlebar blue, as other titlebars in Outlook are.

But I can't find a way to do that in the manifest. Am I missing something?

Can anyone point me to how I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742073/outlook-web-add-in-change-color-of-the-title-bar and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59753727/change-title-bars-background-colour-in-outlook-web-addin .
Currently changing the background color of the title bar is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process .

Comment: User voice link is :- https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/59742073/… and stackoverflow.com/questions/59753727/… . Currently changing the background color of the title bar is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process .User voice link is