# Change title bar's background colour in Outlook web-addin

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I would like to change the title bar's background colour. I see  in the xml file which produces the title. What is the way to hook into the title bar to change the background colour? I see a similar questions for C# [Is there any way to change border/header background in VSTO outlook add in?][1]

[1]: [Is there any way to change border/header background in VSTO outlook add in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285132/is-there-any-way-to-change-border-header-background-in-vsto-outlook-add-in) Is there something similar we can do here with the webaddin?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742073/outlook-web-add-in-change-color-of-the-title-bar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook Web-add in - Change color of the title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742073/outlook-web-add-in-change-color-of-the-title-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Currently changing the background color of the title bar is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process